# Haskell last string

Tags: string, haskell, ghc

I'm trying to make a function that takes the last character from a string and add it to be the first character. In string I can do this (xs:x) and then x is the last character?

Comment: I've downvoted this question. As it stands, the question-as-asked can be trivially answered by the time-honored Try It And See method. To ask a better question, you should play with things on your own a bit, and ideally consult your favorite tutorial and search engine, then bring us the result of that hard work. Doing those things will also help you sharpen your question; the closer you can get to identifying the core thing you don't yet understand, the easier it will be for you to engage with an answer.

Comment: The names of the variables do not matter, so `(x:xs)`, is just the same as `(xs:x)`. A `(_:_)` is just a node in a linked list. So if you need the last item, you will need to "walk" through the string.

Answer (score 1):

x*s* is just a naming convention for lists in Haskell (which you should use!). (x:xs) is a pattern matching using the (:) function, it is up to you how you name it e.g. (this:makesnosense) is also valid.

Also remember that a String is just another list, so your question is equal to: "How can I make the last element of a list the first one."

This would be one way to solve it:

```
lastToFirst :: [a] -> [a]
lastToFirst [] = []
lastToFirst [x] = [x]
lastToFirst xs = last xs : init xs
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to make a function that takes away the last character from a string and add it to be the first character.

In Haskell, list operator ':' is asymmetric. If the left operand is of type α, the right operand must be of type [α]. Hence, a pattern such as `xs:x` is just using misleading variable names. The operator is right-associative, so that `x0:x1:xs` means `x0:(x1:xs)`.

Unlike Python lists, which are basically arrays, Haskell lists are just forward-chained linked lists. Classic imperative languages often maintain both a pointer to the head of a linked list and to its tail, but the main point of the tail pointer is to be able to *append* new elements at the tail of the list.

As Haskell lists are immutable, the tail pointer would be mostly useless, and so Haskell only maintains a pointer to the head of a list.

This means there is no cheap way to access the last element. The only way is to traverse the whole list, starting from the head. Furthermore, immutability implies that the only way to generate the [1,2,3] list from the [1,2,3,4] list is by *duplicating* the first 3 elements, which again require a full traversal.

So an expression such as `last xs : init xs`, if compiled naïvely, implies **2** costly traversals of the input list.

The best one can hope is to *leverage* the duplication work to grab the last element at no extra cost, thus solving the problem in a single traversal. This can be done, for example, by recursion:

```
makeLastFirst :: [a] -> [a]
makeLastFirst  []            =    []      -- empty input list
makeLastFirst  [end]         =    [end]   -- just the last element
makeLastFirst  (x0:(x1:xs))  =    let  (end:ys)  =  makeLastFirst (x1:xs)
                                  in   end : (x0:ys)
```

where the recursive clause takes care of keeping the input tail element at the head of the output list.

### Watching the gears turn:

One can visualize the recursive process by importing package  `Debug.Trace` and using its `trace` function. Expression `trace msg value` evaluates to just `value`, but has the *side effect* of printing the `msg` string. Yes, side effects are normally forbidden in Haskell, but function `trace` has special privileges.

So we can write a more talkative version of our function:

```
import  Debug.Trace

traceMakeLastFirst :: Show a => [a] -> [a]
traceMakeLastFirst  []            =    []      -- empty input list
traceMakeLastFirst  [end]         =    [end]   -- just the last element
traceMakeLastFirst  (x0:(x1:xs))  =    let  (end:ys)  = traceMakeLastFirst (x1:xs)
                                            result    =  end : (x0:ys)
                                       in  trace (show result) result
```

Testing under the `ghci` interpreter:

```
$ ghci
 GHCi, version 8.8.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
 λ> 
 λ> :load q66927560.hs
 ...
 Ok, one module loaded.
 λ> 
 λ> traceMakeLastFirst  ""
 ""
 λ> 
 λ> traceMakeLastFirst  "a"
 "a"
 λ> 
 λ> makeLastFirst  "Mercury"
 "yMercur"
 λ> 
 λ> traceMakeLastFirst  "Mercury"
 ""yr"
 "yur"
 "ycur"
 "yrcur"
 "yercur"
 "yMercur"
 yMercur"
 λ>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- makeLastFirst "abcd"   == "dabc"
-- makeLastFirst "hello"  == "ohell"
-- makeLastFirst "orange" == "eorang"

makeLastFirst :: [a] -> [a]
makeLastFirst lst = [ head (reverse lst) ] ++ (init lst)
```